# What's a good structure for an edit function in which all parameters are optionals?

Tags: php

Let's get it simple, a table with three parameters (A, B and C). `A` is the key and is not editable, but `B` and `C` can be modified.

What's the best way of defining an editing function? Because what I have so far is...

```
function edit($b, $c){
    if {($b != "") && ($c != "")){
        update($b, $c);
    }elseif ($b != ""){
        update($b);
    }elseif ($c != ""){
        update($c);
    else {
        die("Anything to edit")
    }
}
```

In this case it's not kind of a big deal, but what if instead of two parameters there are 10 optional parameters? I'm pretty sure there must be some better way of defining such function.

Comment: Where are you getting $b and $c from?

Comment: Have you looked at `func_get_args` and `func_get_arg` and I suppose also `func_num_args`? Incidentally there is a mistake with your code above - `if {(` should be `if( (`

Answer (score 0):

I would run a loop on the value array (not sure how you are getting the values)

```
<?php

    $a = "A";
    $b = "B";
    $c = "C";
    $d = "D";
    $e = "E";

    $param = [$b, $c, $e];

    foreach($param as $value){

        // If $variable isset and not empty
        if(isset($value) && !empty($value)){

            echo ($value."<br/>");  
            // update($value);

        }
    }

?>
```